# Libreoffice Calc sum/merge rows by timestamp?

Tags: cryptocurrency, libreoffice-calc, tax

I have a spreadsheet similar to this, consisting of crypto transactions, with 5k+ entries.

However the exchange has chopped each transaction into 3 separate entries (Rec,Sent,Fee).
Sometimes the transaction is also split before the chop, resulting in 6 entries (as shown below @ the second timestamp).

```
  | Timestamp           | Type    | Received | Sent | Fee |
---------------------------------------------
|1| 03/15/2018 19:55:44 | Rec     | 4.5      |      |     |
|2| 03/15/2018 19:55:44 | Sent    |          | 5    |     |
|3| 03/15/2018 19:55:44 | Fee     |          |      | 0.5 |
|4| 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Rec     | 2.8      |      |     |
|5| 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Sent    |          | 3    |     |
|6| 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Fee     |          |      | 0.2 |
|7| 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Rec     | 4.2      |      |     |
|8| 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Sent    |          | 5    |     |
|9| 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Fee     |          |      | 0.8 |
```

For tax purposes I need them as one entry...

How do I get every row with the same timestamp to merge/sum vertically into a single row?

The Received,Sent,Fee columns will never overlap.

The result should be something like this...

```
  | Timestamp           | Type  | Received | Sent | Fee |
---------------------------------------------
|1| 03/15/2018 19:55:44 | trade | 4.5      | 5    | 0.5 |
|2| 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | trade | 7        | 8    | 1   |
```

This also works, as I can sort the Type column to remove the remnant Rec,Sent,Fee entries.

```
   | Timestamp           | Type    | Received | Sent | Fee |
---------------------------------------------
|1 | 03/15/2018 19:55:44 | trade   | 4.5      | 5    | 0.5 |
|2 | 03/15/2018 19:55:44 | Rec     | 4.5      |      |     |
|3 | 03/15/2018 19:55:44 | Sent    |          | 5    |     |
|4 | 03/15/2018 19:55:44 | Fee     |          |      | 0.5 |
|5 | 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | trade   | 7        | 8    | 1   |
|6 | 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Rec     | 2.8      |      |     |
|7 | 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Sent    |          | 3    |     |
|8 | 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Fee     |          |      | 0.2 |
|9 | 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Rec     | 4.2      |      |     |
|10| 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Sent    |          | 5    |     |
|11| 09/20/2018 10:15:33 | Fee     |          |      | 0.8 |
```

The important part is that I have at least one entry where they're combined.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just choose [**Insert - Pivot Table**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/12090102.html), drag and drop the desired fields and click **OK**

[image: Using Pivot Table]